# Bash, sed/awk/grep filework removing specific rows

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to find and remove specific rows, but it only works partially

My file:(filename, date, count, path to file)

```
test1.txt;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file1
test2;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file1
test3.txt;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file2
```

Script parameters:

- `$1` = directory(last column)
- `$2` = filename(first column)

My goals:

- A) I want to save the filename of the columns ending with $2 and write them out
- B) I want to remove the whole row with the Given $1 and $2 argument

What I got so far:

```
#This only gets the last part of path/to/file -> 'file' in this case
EndOfDirPath=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\(^.*\)\/\(.*\)/\2/'`
#This removes the files starting with the inputed filename and last part of #directory
sed -i '/^'$2'.*'$EndOfDirPath'$/d' file
```

What I want it to do:

```
$ foo test2 /path/to/file1
test1.txt
test2
```

and the file should look like:

```
test1.txt;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file1
test3.txt;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file2
```

Any tips would help!

Comment: why do you expect `test3.txt;2018-03-16;2;/path/to/file2` in the output even though your argument is `/path/to/file1`??

Comment: that is not the output, that is just the file after running the wanted script with the arguments of the file.
foo(name of the script) test2 (-> $1) /path/to/file1(->$2)
when I run the script I want to write the FILENAMES on stdout which have the same path as $2
Than I want to DELETE $1(test2) If it has also the same $2(Path)
Else the file stays the same

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the order of parameters between your code and call got swapped? I presume the first field (filename) is the first and last field (directory) is second and you only want the last portion (base filename) from that.

It should also be noted `sed` is probably not the easiest choice to work with here. What you are looking for is to process a file in-place while also emitting something along the way on the console. Extra `p` commands would just end up in the same stream/file you're working on. `w` to `/dev/stdout` does not seem to be a supported use of write. Could be done by two passes of sed of course. Or using a different tool entirely (perhaps a Python or Perl script).

You could also go the other way around, print along the way and instead of in place write results into a new file, but I did figure out a way to use `sed` (once) and not need one additional file. For a single pass of `sed` I got the following (not dealing with safe tempfile creation and clean-up):

```
sed -i '/\<'"$(basename $2)"'$/{
        h
        s/;.*//
        w tempfile
        x
    }
    /^'$1'.*\<'"$(basename $2)"'$/d' file
cat tempfile
```

What does it do? In the first block, I take each line that ends with base name (last portion of a path) of the second parameter. I save it into hold space `h` (so that I can chop of bits but still have the intact line later). Then I remove everything past first semicolon (`;`). Write (`w`) it into a file named `tempfile`. And swap pattern space with hold space thus restoring the original line (`x`). In the second block I do the same action you've had before. Remove all lines starting with first param and end ending with last path component of the second.

Note that for the second parameter matching, I've prefixed it with `\<` to make sure `/path/to/file1` would not also end up matching `/path/to/xfile1` as would otherwise be the case. If you wanted to keep the whole path, you would need to use a different character since the slashes in the path would upset `sed`, you could for instance say: `'\#'"$2"'#'`

Just for sake of completeness, the two pass option:

```
sed -ne '/\<'"$(basename $2)"'$/s/;.*//p' file
sed -i '/^'$1'.*\<'"$(basename $2)"'$/d' file
```

Having said all that. Still probably best yet not to do this specific task with `sed`. ;)